# Gap between rows in tablelayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to make a 6x6 tile-game. 
So I made a layout with 6x6 imageView, thought that would be easy enough. 
But no, I got spaces between rows and I've been trying for some time now to get them away but nothing seems to work.

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/game_text" >
    </TextView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dip"
         >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col1"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col3"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col4"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col5"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col6"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col1"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col3"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col4"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col5"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col6"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="0dip">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col1"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col3"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col4"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col5"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col6"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col1"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col3"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col4"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col5"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col6"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col1"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col3"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col4"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col5"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col6"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col1"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col2"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col3"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col4"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col5"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col6"
                android:layout_weight="0.16" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GridView instead of TableLayout. So that you can adjust the width and height of rows and columns.

Comment: Can one make them adaptive so the size of the boxes changes depending on the users screen?

Comment: Gridview has Gridview height and width you can set them as wrap_content

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the layout_weight. The default layout_weight for a layout is 1 which is normally fine because you can use divide that number. In your case, however, you have 6 items per row. That means you have to divide 1 by 6 and that gives you the number 0.166666666_ and you simply have 0.16.

What you can do to fix this is give the layout a layout_weight of 6 and each image view a layout_weight of 1. **Try this.** I have just added android:layout_weight="6" to the Linear Layout and changed all the android:layout_weight="0.16" to android:layout_weight="1" .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/game_text" >
    </TextView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dip"
         >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col2"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col4"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row1col6"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col2"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col4"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row2col6"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="0dip">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col2"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col4"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row3col6"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col2"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col4"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row4col6"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col2"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col4"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row5col6"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col1"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col2"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col3"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col4"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col5"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/row6col6"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ImageView>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if it works, I didn't have your images to load. If it doesn't work, or post a screenshot and someone else may know the solution.